# Google Apps Script with Gmail: Search, Rename and Forward specific mails

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, rename, forward

I'm curious to learn if the following scenario can be addressed using Google Apps Script (or perhaps another method?). Here's the scenario I'm dealing with.

Perform a specific subject line search when new messages are received. For example:

- ({subject:(keyword1 keyword2 keyword3)  subject:(keyword1 keyword4 keyword5)})

If matched, perform the following actions:

1. Modify the subject line to include "#action"
2. Forward this newly renamed mail to another email address

Bonus points if I can somehow then label the original email, and archive said original mail (removing it from my inbox) in one fell swoop.

Help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify), you can only modify the labels of a Gmail message but not the subject or body.

To forward an email to another account, or to archive an email, you could use the message.forward() and moveThreadsToArchive() methods in Google Apps Script.

```
function archiveMessages() {
  var query = 'label:archiveme';
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);      
  GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads);
  threads.forEach(function(thread) {
    thread.getMessages().forEach(function(message) {
          message.forward("recipient@example.com");
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As a secondary question, is there any way to trigger sending a new automated message upon receipt of mail that matches a search? For example, a new mail arrives that matches a subject search, and an Apps Script sends a new mail to the forwarding address with the subject “#action” instead of attempting to rename and forward the original mail?